# объект, который возвращает другой объект

Tags: php

Каким образом можно сделать так, что бы при создании класса `A` он возвращал объект класса `B`? Без использования доп. методов (т.е. через конструктор или магические методы)?

Решить буду такую задачу:

нужно создать класс wrappper, который в конструкторе будет создавать сложный класс, конфигурировать его и возвращать котовый объект?

Comment: В теории можно использовать __toString(), но как по мне это костыль. Лучше делать getter и все. Почему не должно быть доп методов то?

Comment: А нельзя просто в конструкторе создавать экземпляр другого класса? Что мешает то? 
`class A { pubic $b; public function __construct() { $this->b = new B; } } `

Comment: @InDevX создам в конструкторе, что дальше?  Его же вернуть как-то надо.. 

В целом понял.. сделаю через геттеры. Я думал, что может можно как-то через конструктор return сделать или маг. методы как-то.. Чтобы писать `$result = new A; // а получить объект B `

Comment: Можно через __toString, будет примерно так 
$objectB = echo (new A(params));

Comment: Но это бред, лучше через getter, конструктор не может ничего возвращать

Comment: +- так же можно и через getter 
$result = (new A(params)->getB();

Comment: @sadfsdfsdf а далее вы делаете что угодно с данными и возвращаете объект.. Я не пойму - в чём проблема то? Вы не знаете как объект возвращать?... Создаёте метод который будет собирать и возвращать нужные данные и просто вызываете его в конструкторе. профит

Comment: Может вам стоит лучше взглянуть на паттерн фабрики чем изобретать велосипед?

Comment: статический метод сделайте, который будет возвращать нужные классы, и запретите вообще инстанциирование объектов. все равно судя по вашему описанию они использоваться не будут и не смогут.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте в классе поле для хранения объекта необходимого вам класса и в конструкторе инициализируйте это поле.  После создайте метод который будет возвращать данное поле.

Answer (score 0):

Конструктор в РНР ничего не возвращает. Т.е. создать-то в конструкторе можно что угодно, но вот чтобы получить это, будет нужен какой-то еще метод.

На какие только ухищения не идут люди, лишь бы не использовать нормальный фреймворк, где все уже реализовано.

Comment: пусть соображалка работает, прально делает, так быстрее окунется...